# Make a QHBoxLayout accesible in an Instance of a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I want to Subclass a QWidget...

```
 Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ImgWidget)
{
    // Is this the right place or does it need to be outside like: Widget::layout...
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    ...
    hLayout->addWidget( someWidget );
    this->setLayout(hLayout);
}
```

...and then in an instance i would like to add a widget to the layout like

```
Widget *widget = new Widget();
...
widget->hLayout->addWidget( someOtherWidget );
```

The equivalent in Python would be done by the 'self' keyword like `self.layout = QHBoxLayout()` but i think it cant be done with the `this` keyword

But more general... What is the best way to do this in C++ because i used it a lot with pyqt

Comment: Yes. corrected some spelling btw

Answer (score 2):

Any `QWidget` can provide access to the layout via the [`layout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#layout) function.

```
Widget* widget = new Widget();
QLayout* layout = widget->layout();
```

I don't know why you want to externally modify the layout of the widget but at this point you need knowledge of that actual layout type. With knowledge of the layout type you can cast and use it.

```
QHBoxLayout* hLayout = qobject_cast<QHBoxLayout>(layout);
```

Comment: maybe there is a better solution, yes. And i think i already got it. The equivalent of `self.hLayout.addWidget( widget )` would be a member function of my subclass i guess like: `void widget::addWidget(QWidget *widget) {...}` The thing is it is more of a beginners question about the structure for any subclasses

Comment: @tobilocker Yes, `self` would be `this` in C++ and using `this` requires a class member function.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a function addSubWidget ( QWidget* aubWidget ), the rest of the code is ok, and make hLayout private. Or batter, use the layout function with a cast, like @James sugested.

In c++ it is just recomended, not mandatory to use this->hLayout to be sure you do notshadow it with a local variable with the same name.